# question on class definitions

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I saw that the following two class definitions are claimed to be equivalent. Is that true? How?   Thanks.

```
class  complex{
double re, im;
public:
  complex( ): re(0) , im(0) { }
  complex (double  r): re(r), im(0)  { }
  complex (double  r, double i): re(r),   im(i) { }
};
class  complex{
  double re, im;
  public:
    complex (double  r=0, double i=0): re(r),   im(i) { }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one lists all the possibilities (no parameter, one parameter, two parameters) separately ([overloading](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/overl.htm)), the second one only needs one function because of usage of [default parameters](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters/), which is exactly the same but much shorter.

The first one is still useful if initialization of variables is more than just assigning a value to them or you want to have completely different constructors depending on the parameter count.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the are not equivalent (after all, the second has only one constructor while the first has three), but they behave equally. A constructor with nonzero arguments providing default values for all of them qualifies as a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They're equivalent. But the second one is better in my opinion,as it's compact, taking advantage of one C++ feature called [**default argument**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7l.doc/language/ref/clrc07cplr237.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
class  complex{
  double re, im;
  public:
    complex (double  r=0, double i=0): re(r),   im(i) { }
};
```

Is a simplified way of implementing the first version. It basically covers all the cases of the the three constructors in first one.

Answer (score 0):

The default values (r=0) in the latter example allow for the arguments to be partially or fully omitted.
Thus the one constructor method comprises all three variants from the top example.